# Is there an alternative application launcher for Openbox on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, launcher, openbox

For Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed OpenBox. I like it, but want to know if there is an alternative application launcher. I like ADeskBar, but I can't get it to install because of "unmet dependencies" of some sort.

Comment: Are you looking for a "dock bar" type application ? Like on OSX, with fancy bits or something light and fast, more like Openbox was. If you post the "unmet dependencies" error in full we can probably get Adeskbar working, if you like that one.

Comment: I just need something simple like the old win95 start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend lxpanel, its in the repo's

```
sudo apt-get install lxpanel
```

This is the default menu and taskbar from LXDE, has a start menu on the left and you can pin, close, open etc... from the taskbar.

I would describe this as Windows 95 like, so it should suit your needs

[image]

Comment: This did the trick. I also liked how I could restyle it to almost look like the Chrome OS bar instead of the KDE appearance you have in your screenshot. I added a ~/.config/openbox/autostart file to launch this as well as nautilus on booting into Openbox.